# Better jumping in unity 2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, move

I am currently working on a 2d game, and for jumping, I'm using `Rigidbody.Addforce()`. However, this causes my player to land back to the ground slowly. I want it to land back quickly.

I tried manipulating the values of Gravity scale and mass, but that causes effects over player movement and again that jump doesn't come out well.

Here's the code:-

```cs
    private void Update()
    {
        if (IsGrounded == true)
        {
            extraJumps = 1;        
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0 && PlayerCanMove == true) //Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended
        {
            if (CheckGrounded() == true && OnSlope() == false)
            {
                Catanim.SetBool("isJumping", true);                        
                IsJumping = true;
                RBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce * 1000f);
                extraJumps = extraJumps - 1;
                
   
            }
            else if(CheckGrounded() == true && OnSlope() == true)
            {
                Catanim.SetBool("isJumping", true);                        
                IsJumping = true;
                RBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce * 1000f);
                extraJumps = extraJumps - 1;
                

            }
            else
            {
                IsJumping = false;
                Catanim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Here's an image of the rigidbody2d component:-
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnh69.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, to make a better jump, you need a condition to determine the up and down movement. The code below is the key to solving the problem.

```cs
if (RBody.velocity.y > 0) // moving UpSide
{
    RBody.gravityScale = 1;
}
else // moving on ground
{
    RBody.gravityScale = 2; // double gravity scale for jumping down
}
```

And to summarize the code:

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (IsGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = 1;        
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && ...)
    {
        ...
    }

    RBody.gravityScale = RBody.velocity.y > 0 ? 1f : 2f; // define upside gravity first and down side gravity second
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm planning to use this method for my player movement as well as similar problem is seen while movement as well. 

I hope that won't cause any harm to the gameplay or will it?

Comment: @hallmk7 If your movement is simple and managed, no; But if the code structure becomes very complicated and you want to create ability system and buff system later. Create an auxiliary `gravityScale` variable and pass it through the **Change Tunnel** while refreshing it every frame.

Comment: alright. I instead used a different technique. I used RigidBody.AddForce() but in negative y direction depending on different conditions within my game. I think that should be a better option instead of setting gravity scale?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a character controller and making your gravity if you are trying to make a 2D game. However, if you want to stick to rigid body and want to adjust your gravity your can do that:

```
 public float gMoon=1.6f;  //gravity on the moon.
     void Start()
     {
         rb=GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
     }
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, -1.0f, 0)*rb.mass*gMoon);  
     }
```

Comment: so should i increase gravity while jumping and reset it back to normal when on ground back?

And i didn't understand what you're trying to tell with the script? Why are we adding force in fixed update in y direction?

Comment: You apply a force in y constantly to act as the force that keep you on the ground. The force get applied constantly while you are in the air to make you fall faster as you spend time in the air. A fis not exactly a fixed translation, it's just a movement force you apply to an object, hence why I suggested to use a character controller instead, since you can have better control of it

Comment: so apart from this,

 RBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce * 1000f);

i should use this as well?

 rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, -1.0f, 0)*rb.mass*gMoon);  

this is what you mean right?  Actually i'm new to unity so don't know many of these tricks. Secondly, can you please suggest some links for a good character controller, provided my game even involves slopes....

Comment: No, you want to either use a character controller or rigidbody. There is a lot of tutorial on youtube on how to use character controller